# Stuck with Owl carousel - Can't make it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I started building my website (WordPress custom theme with Boostrap front-end framework). 
I put inside files in it but i still am not getting it to work.
Everything is visible but I cant slide it.
I Have checked that files are loaded properly.

These are the files i have loaded on the page
- jquery-1.11.0.min.js (from bootstrap)

- jquery.min.js (came together with owl folder)
- owl.carousel.min.js
- owl.carousel.min.css
- owl.theme.default.min.css

I have tried turning of jquery-1.11.0.min.js but keeping jquery.min.js.
I have also tried turning off jquery.min.js and keeping jquery-1.11.0.min.js but no results.

Has anyone had same problem?

---

I tried setting up an jsfiddle but somehow the carousel doesn't show up at all there.
Here is the link anyways so you can see the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/ykhu3aa0/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="loop owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
        <div class="owl-stage-outer">
            <div class="owl-stage" style="transition: 0.25s; width: 5880px; transform: translate3d(-2572px, 0px, 0px);">
                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item active center" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 235px; margin-right: 10px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x220">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="owl-nav disabled"><div class="owl-prev">prev</div><div class="owl-next">next</div></div>

        <div class="owl-dots">
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $('.loop').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    items:2,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsive:{
        600:{
            items:4
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The reason your fiddle isn't working is because you don't have the https:// prefix in front of all of the resources you are loading.

The https versions don't seem to work on your server either.

Comment: Paste only the codes you are using while making carousel

Comment: Are you using jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  Your code here  }); ?

Comment: @acewebdesign Thanks

Comment: @sagar Yes i did

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't. Is it mandatory to put it to work ?

Comment: do u need that bit of code to run the owl why are u pasting all those clone items over there

Comment: Yes, its mandatory. See the sample demo https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's running now, I think?

```
$(function(){
  $('.loop').owlCarousel({
      center: true,
      items:2,
      loop:true,
      margin:10,
      responsive:{
          600:{
              items:4
          }
      }
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ykhu3aa0/4/